# Twilio function - exports event object undefined

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a Twilio function, as below; it forwards the SMS to an email address.
In the phone number's configuration, I am calling this function when 'A message comes in'. There is no other component involved - no callback, no Messaging Service, no Studio, nada.

```
const got = require('got');
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    console.log(event.to);

    const requestBody = {
        subject: `sms to [${event.to}, from ${event.From}`, 
        //build rest of JSON request
    }
    
    got.post('https://api.mailclient.com/v3/mail/send', {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${context.DEV__API_TOKEN}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    .then(response => {
          let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
          callback(null, twiml);
   })
   .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        callback(err, 'error');
   });

};
```

I am testing the setup by sending an SMS from a mobile phone. Of course the email goes through, but the ${event.to} always turns up as 'undefined'. I am not sure what am I missing. Any pointers, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the incoming request the parameters are all capitalised values. You are already correctly using `event.From`, so you just need to change `event.to` to `event.To` and it will no longer be `undefined`.